# Add custom content to post based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add custom content before the main post content based on category.

What I'd tried and **it actually works** is to insert the custom code in the second paragraph:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'mte_add_incontent_ad');
function mte_add_incontent_ad($content)
{   if(is_single()){
        $content_block = explode('<p>',$content);
        if(!empty($content_block[1]))
        {   $content_block[1] .= 'My custom text here!';
        }
        for($i=1;$i<count($content_block);$i++)
        {   $content_block[$i] = $content_block[$i];
        }
        $content = implode('',$content_block);
    }
    return $content;    
}
```

I found a simple solution to put the custom text in a specific category but it does not seem to work:

```
if ( in_category('my-category-1-slug') ) { 
 echo '<p>
custom text to insert
</p>';
 }
if ( in_category('my-category-2-slug') ) { 
 echo '<p>
custom text to insert
</p>';
 }
```

The final results should be something like this:

Post Title

Custom post content for category 1.
Original post content.

---

Post Title

Custom post content for category 2.
Original post content.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'mte_add_incontent_ad');
function mte_add_incontent_ad($content)
{   if( is_category(1) ){
        $content_block = explode('<p>',$content);
        if(!empty($content_block[1]))
        {   $content_block[1] .= 'My custom text for category 1';
        }
        for($i=1;$i<count($content_block);$i++)
        {   $content_block[$i] = $content_block[$i];
        }
        $content = implode('',$content_block);
    }
    return $content;    
}
```